# wordpress 4.4 upgrade visual editor bullets select for not selected elements

Tags: javascript, tinymce, visual-editor

[image]

Please check attachment for reference image and help me to fix it please.

Comment: I was upgraded version 3.9.9 and it's fixed. don't know whats issue in latest version of word press.